# Cannot find module './..../x.html' - TsLint / Angular-Meteor

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, angular-meteor, tslint

I've got a problem with the TsLint of my angular-meteor project.

I am currently following the tutorial at http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/routing-and-multiple-views. Whenever I try to import a template-html file inline, I get an error that the module does not exist. The code however works perfectly when I compile and run it.

How can I modify my tslint-compiler so it understands these modules and so it stops spamming we with these 'errors'. I use Visual Studio Code as a source code editor.

Here you can find what the errors look like. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Maybe your tsconfig.json file is restricted to *.ts files.

Comment: Here's my tsconfig{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "client/**/*.ts",
    "server/**/*.ts",
    "typings/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

Comment: Have you tried to add 'client/**/*.html' in filesGlob ?

Comment: I tried it but to no avail..

Comment: Have you tried this : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4019 ? See last comment.

Comment: I have the same problem and after some reading:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2709
It seems there is general community support for allowing for the following code to satisfy the type requirements and avoid this error:

    `import template:string from './somefile.html';`

Its kinda irritating as is...

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work without extension (at least in Ionic 2 which is built upon Angular 2)

`import template from './views/question-details';`

This is using Netbeans 8.2 dev edition + nbts https://github.com/Everlaw/nbts/releases

Comment: I am in the same boat as the OP and this doesn't work in our case.